# Using div tag in html without using css

Tags: html

I have to make an html page without using css...
the problem is that, that i want to use div tag and add an image as my background and write some content over the image, so please suggest me ways to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried Anything ? For the image you have for example  `<body background="yourimage.jpg">`

Answer (score 0):

Some examples, with this you don't need to include/insert all css file

```
<body style="background-image:url('http://example.com/background.png')">
```

or

```
<div style="background-image:url('bakground.png')">
```

Without css you can't set background